"a slight final decline" vs "a final slight decline". Opinion adjectives or sequence adjectives comes first?
I was once advised to use "a considerable subsequent decline" instead of "a subsequent considerable decline". With this, I came up with a rule for myself:

Use an "opinion" adjective before a "sequence" adjective.

If that's correct, maybe "a slight final decline" is better than "a final slight decline"? Below is an example sentence:

Car production increased from 1.2 billion in 2008 to 2 million in 2010, but it later saw a slight final decline in the last year examined.


Are there several slight declines, and you are discussing the last one? Or are you saying that the last decline was only slight. Maybe the word "final" should be left out.

I mean to say there were fluctuations in the car production in this country, but the final trend is a decline.

By the way, when I typed the above answer, Grammarly suggested that I remove the word "the" coming before "car production". I got that every time I used "the" with "production". If you don't mind, why does Grammarly suggest so? This is the car production in this country, so it's specific, hence the use of "the".

If the trend really final, or just the latest data? The question about "the" should probably be asked as a new question.

It's the latest data during the given period. The period examined was from 2006 to 2012. The figure decreased from 2006 to 2008, then increased in the next 2 years, and from 2010 to 2012, the last trend it saw was a decline.

To the article question: I can only ask one question every 40 minutes, so I often try to avoid asking something unimportant. But you're right. That question probably needs a long answer. But maybe a short answer to this is not too much: Is "the car production in England in 2010" correct? You could simply say yes or no.

Strike the words "later and "final" is my advice. They add nothing and merely get in the way.  State in the sentence the final year ... saw a slight decline in 2012, the final year examined.

@TimR Yeah maybe in this case that's what I should do. What about others? I still wonder what should come first, a sequence adjective or an opinion adjective.

"A final slight decline" implies there have been previous slight declines. If that is not what you want to imply, say "slight final decline".   But I don't think you need to stack two adjectives in that manner. That is a corner you paint yourself into.
